# sqlplus command problems

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am a newbie to sqlplus. I am trying to write a simple script to extract data to a file.
First problem I am having: It describes the variables on the top of the output file, like

```
Old Value was
New Value is
```

I want this not be output if possible.

Secondly, i am trying to write the contents of a field to a file. The content of the field can vary, I have set the Linesize to 8000 but the return is around 50 characters or so. How do i get the full contents of the field?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent SQL*Plus showing the old and new variable values you need to set [verify](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699432) off:

```
SQL> SET VERIFY OFF
```

To pipe the output to a file you need the [spool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1013669) command:

```
SQL>SPOOL C:\myfile.txt
SQL>SELECT sysdate
  2 FROM dual;

SYSDATE
---------
30-NOV-11

SQL> SPOOL OFF
```

Hope it helps...